# Label are overlapping even after adding constraint in Xamarin.IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, xamarin.ios

Labels are overlapping in Xamarin.IOS and dimension also not expanding with respect to content.

Code in ViewController:

```
   List<class> listofdata = databaseconnectivity.GetListofData(1);
   TableViewSource tableViewsourceObj = new TableViewSource(listofdata, this);
   tableView.Source = tableViewsourceObj;
   tableView.RowHeight = UITableView.AutomaticDimension;
```

Code in GetCell method of TableView Source

```
  var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell((Foundation.NSString)"TVCellIdentifier");
  var cell2 = (VersesTvcCell)cell;   
  cell2.UpdateCell(listofdata[indexPath.Row].field1, listofdata[indexPath.Row].field2);
  return cell2;
```

Code in UpdateCell method of UITableViewCell

```
   Label1.Text = field1;
   Label2.Text = field2;
```

[Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q53ak.png)

[Image of constraints of labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmUQI.png)

Comment: looks to me like they have no constraints set to keep them in place, but that's hard to tell, if you click on one of the UILabels in Storyboard, and select Layout, there should be a list of constraints, could you tell us what they are, on the top UILabel for starters.

Comment: I've added picture of  list of constraints

Comment: ok, has the first label got any constraints? because your top constraing on label 2 is set to the bottom of label 1, but constraints work themselves out based on all connected controls and their constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set constraint as below .

1. FirstLabel  - Leading, Trailing, Top, (Bottom with SecondLabel).
2. SecondLabel - Leading, Trailing, (Bottom with ContentView)
3. Got error, it is about content hugging priority . You can resolve using xcode correction or using set vertical priority higher to secondLabel.

Answer (score 0):

Remove align top for both labels and increase the vertical spacing between them.